# How to creat a multi level dataframe from an excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a multi level dataframe using the multi index `from_frame` method but the result is empty. Do you have any idea?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['DESC', 'Type'], ['DESC', 'Description'],
                      ['PLAN', 'Nb Jours'], ['PLAN', 'Montant']],
                      columns=['first', 'second'])

data = pd.read_excel('c:\\users\\kamran\\work\\data.xlsx', header=None)

print (data)
    0               1    2       3
0  Métier       ELODIE V7  500  400000
1  Métier  Refonte BI.com  600  800000
2     DSI           OPCON  200  150000
3     DSI           WIN10  100   30000


index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df)
sdata =  pd.DataFrame(data, columns=index)
print (sdata)

first  DESC                 PLAN        
second Type Description Nb Jours Montant
0       NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN
1       NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN
2       NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN
3       NaN         NaN      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: how is your data?...I mean your excel

Comment: Could you include your expected result?

Comment: Thank you. My excel file is simple and I can read it with no problem, the result is given in my data variable. My problem is how to convert my data to a multi level data frame looking like below.

Comment: DESC   PLAN
Type Description Jours Montant
0 Métier ELODIE  500 400000
1 Métier Refonte 600 800000
2 DSI OPCON  200 150000
3 DSI WIN10  100 30000

Answer (score 0):

Without further clarification, you may be able to create your desired result using the dataframe [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method:

```
col_0 = ['Métier', 'Métier', 'DSI', 'DSI']
col_1 = ['ELODIE V7', 'Refonte BI.com', 'OPCON', 'WIN10']
col_2 = [500, 600, 200, 100]
col_3 = [400000, 800000, 150000, 30000]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_0':col_0, 'col_1':col_1, 'col_2':col_2, 'col_3':col_3})


df = df.set_index(['col_0','col_1'])
```

which returns:

```
                        col_2    col_3
col_0   col_1       
Métier  ELODIE V7        500    400000
        Refonte BI.com   600    800000
DSI     OPCON            200    150000
        WIN10            100    30000
```